# How to disable XML validation for files with no schema in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: xml, intellij-idea

I'm working on a logback.xml file and as you probably know, logback doesn't have a distinct schema.

So IntelliJ marks every tag as "Cannot resolve symbol".

How can i disable that? I don't want IntelliJ to mark XML files with no schema as errors.

Comment: Try "File | Invalidate caches..." -- may help. Other solutions -- as @Itchy mentioned (will disable ALL inspections for this particular file) or in "Settings | Inspections" -- you can configure inspection for custom scope (use right click on desired inspection).

Answer (score 2):

In the project view, select the file, open up the context menu, (by right-clicking on the file,) and select "Mark as text".

Answer (score 0):

There is an "Inspector" Icon. If you click it, you can change the inspection level.

You can find it at the bar at the bottom, on the right side. Just left to the bar displaying your memory usage.

Comment: Isn't this disables inspections for everything? I want only for this use case, and on my co-worker machine the bar is up to the end but still he doesn't see these errors

Comment: If you want to disable just some specific inspections you can also set the cursor to somewhere where they occur, and then press `alt+Enter`. Then navigate with the arrow keys through the list and select the "Disable Inspection"-Option. But this AFAIK disables this exception for the whole project (although all others still apply). Some inspections can also be disabled only locally.

Comment: I'm sorry but non of the answers help me, because our company uses shared inspection file and it only happens to me, and I couldn't find a way to disable only for this file, it changes everything and this is not my intention

Comment: There is also the `Configure Inspections` link in the inspection popup - it will open the Preferences where you can scroll to XML and pick what exactly you want to validate.

Answer (score 0):

To visualize what Itchy meant:
Uncheck the "Import popup" checkbox.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Inspections]